# Why won't my current version of Laravel 5.7.28 upgrade to 5.8 without getting problem 1 error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to upgrade my current version of Laravel 5.7.28 to 5.8.  What I did was, I wrote `"laravel/framework": "5.8.*"`, then ran `composer update` but all I got was the error below.

I've followed the docs from 5.5 up until now to 5.7 but trying to from 5.7 to 5.8 is giving me issues even though my php version is correct as well as `"laravel/framework": "5.8.*"`.

Note:  I ran `php -m` to check all the required extentions for Laravel 5.8, I have them all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.3.1",
    "blackfire/php-sdk": "^1.13",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "publiux/laravelcdn": "~2.0"
},
```

Error below:

```
 Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.17
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.15
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.14
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.13
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.12
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.11
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.10
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.9
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.8
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.7
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.6
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.5
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.3
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.1
- publiux/laravelcdn v2.0.8 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28], illuminate/support[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
- publiux/laravelcdn v2.0.8 requires illuminate/config 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.*|5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28], illuminate/config[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
- publiux/laravelcdn 2.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- publiux/laravelcdn 2.0.1 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- publiux/laravelcdn 2.0.2 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- publiux/laravelcdn 2.0.3 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- publiux/laravelcdn v2.0.4 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- publiux/laravelcdn v2.0.5 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44].
- publiux/laravelcdn v2.0.6 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
- publiux/laravelcdn v2.0.7 requires illuminate/support 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.*|5.6.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.8.0, v5.7.28].
- don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
```

Comment: There should be more error output than that. One of your other packages likely requires a specific Laravel version that isn't 5.8 and may need an upgrade too.

Comment: @ceejayoz just posted the whole error.

Comment: Your update confirms my theory. `publiux/laravelcdn` doesn't support Laravel 5.8. https://github.com/publiux/laravelcdn/issues/52

Comment: @ceejayoz ah ok, how do I go about fixing it?  sorry I'm kinda new to this :)

Comment: You can wait for the library to be updated, remove the library, or you can fork the library. It [looks like](https://github.com/publiux/laravelcdn/pull/54) the last approach won't be too difficult; it may just need an updated `composer.json`.

Comment: gotcha, what should my `composer.json` look like so I can 5.8 to work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193716/discussion-between-mr-test-and-ceejayoz).

Comment: It's not *your* `composer.json`, it's that package's. You'd need to [fork the package, make your adjustments, and use that forked package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004113/working-on-forked-github-repository-through-composer). I'm not able to walk you through that process - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004113/working-on-forked-github-repository-through-composer.

Comment: @ceejayoz ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a current pull request for 5.8 that is green. https://github.com/duxthefux/laravelcdn/tree/laravel-5.8. For steps on how to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498519/how-to-require-a-fork-with-composer

Answer (score 0):

One of your dependencies, `publiux/laravelcdn`, [doesn't yet support Laravel 5.8](https://github.com/publiux/laravelcdn/issues/52).

Comment: @mrtest From your output, it looks like the only conflicting package. Removing it will presumably have side effects, though. You may have to find a replacement, or make some adjustments to your code to deal with the missing library.